# overriding admin js and py files in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I have to override certain js and py files in django. I could override the templates but what should I do about the js and py files. I can see that the django admin has included html tags like 
 right in the py files. Is this the right practice? They should have used some sort of templates rather than including tags like 
 right in the py files. Also how am I supposed to override the js files at the whole application level?

Comment: For eg in the django's admin's widget.py file it has included the <br/> tag in the class AdminSplitDateTime and admin's DateTimeShortcuts.js file. How am I supposed to override this? Should I override the class itself? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

About changing the .py files, I have no idea. But you could add and/or overwrite some javascript functionality doing something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from settings import MEDIA_URL
from myshop.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # inlines, fields, filter or anything else you want to add    

    class Media:
        js = (MEDIA_URL + 'js/jquery.js',
               MEDIA_URL + 'js/my_own_javascript.js')

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```